# Append a row from newly added csv file to the old one in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, file

I am trying to write a script which will be taking a particular column from a newly added to the folder csv file, and adding it as a row to an old csv file. So, the program should be executing this script whenever a new csv file is added to the folder resulting in one big csv file with many rows.

I have a program which appends csv files into one like this:

```
path = r'/Users/.../Desktop/files' # use your path

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

frame.to_csv(r'/Users/.../Desktop/files/New.csv', index = False)
```

But it doesn't really do the full job, as what I want is this row from the newly added file (without a header):

[image]

to be appended into this type of file:

[image]

It is supposed to be happening whenever the new csv file is dropped to the folder, so maybe `time.sleep()` function should be used.

I really hope you can help.. I got totally lost when I tried to write the whole script.. :(

P.S. Sorry for the wordiness :/

Comment: So you were expecting the columns as rows and then concat (append) the new row

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I want to select only one column => append it as a row to another file. Do you know what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, with the following dataframes:

```py
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"],
        "col1": [244, 65, 22, 97, 147, 89, 6, 88, 49, 34],
        "col2": [122, 43, 12, 87, 100, 70, 3, 54, 18, 82],
    }
)
print(frame)
# Output
  ID  col1  col2
0  A   244   122
1  B    65    43
2  C    22    12
3  D    97    87
4  E   147   100
5  F    89    70
6  G     6     3
7  H    88    54
8  I    49    18
9  J    34    82
```

```py
old_csv = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Time Point": [1],
        "A": [9],
        "B": [14],
        "C": [219],
        "D": [54],
        "E": [99],
        "F": [78],
        "G": [5],
        "H": [77],
        "I": [65],
        "J": [44],
    }
)
print(old_csv)
# Output
   Time Point  A   B    C   D   E   F  G   H   I   J
0           1  9  14  219  54  99  78  5  77  65  44
```

You could try this:

```py
new_row = pd.DataFrame(frame.loc[:, "col2"]).T.rename(
    columns={
        k: v for k, v in enumerate(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"])
    }
)


new_csv = pd.concat([old_csv, new_row]).reset_index(drop=True)
new_csv.at[len(old_csv), "Time Point"] = (
    len(old_csv) + 1
)
new_csv["Time Point"] = new_csv["Time Point"].astype(int)

print(new_csv)
# Ouput
   Time Point    A   B    C   D    E   F  G   H   I   J
0           1    9  14  219  54   99  78  5  77  65  44
1           2  122  43   12  87  100  70  3  54  18  82
```